# Applying Page Indexing or Pagination to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination

I have a `ICollection` class `LabCollection` with an array list. This array list contains another class `LabEntity`. LabEntity has properties LabID, LabName etc.

I am binding ICollection class to gridview:

```
LabCollection objLabCollection = new LabCollection();
gridview.DataSource = objlabCollection;
gridview.DataBind();
```

I want to apply page indexing / pagination to gridview, how can I do that using the above.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What page-indexing do you want? What have you tried?

Comment: I mean about page indexing in gridview. Earlier i am using data table to bind to grid view and using data view for event page indexchanging to implement page indexing in grid view.Now i am using Icollection class in mentioned above as datasource.I want to know how page indexing can apply in event pageindexchanging for gridview using Icollection.

Answer (score 1):

Set `AllowPaging=True` with `PageSize=x` in gridview markup, replace `x` with any number like 10.

*Markup:*

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="gridview_PageIndexChanging" runat="server" />
```

*Code-behind:*

```
protected void gridview_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e){
    FillGrid();
    gridview.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gridview.DataBind();
}
```